# Problem hovering a icon link inside a list

Tags: html, css, hover, icons

first time posting a question here, hope someone can help!
I want to create a list of social media icon/links

```
    <div class="social-links">
    <ul>
      <li class="m-link">
        <a href=""><i class="far fa-envelope"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li class="m-link">
        <a href=""><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li class="m-link">
        <a href=""><i class="far fa-address-card"></i></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

```
  .m-link {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  line-height: 2em;
  color: #e2e2e2;
  border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.m-link:hover {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  color: #0b0a08;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #9ecaed;
}
.m-link a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #e2e2e2;
}
```

My problem is that in this way the hover color doesn't apply on the icon/link, I tried to add an extra hover just for the ".m-link a" like so..

```
.m-link a:hover {
  color: #0b0a08;
}
```

but in this way the color apply only when my cursor is on the link and not when I hover on the list element.
Still a beginner here, someone help pleaseeee!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to target the  element inside the  element on hover, like this

```css
.m-link:hover a > i { /* 'on hover on .m-link class element, then i inside a will take this css code */
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  color: #0b0a08;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #9ecaed;
}
```

```css
 .m-link {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  line-height: 2em;
  color: #e2e2e2;
  border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.m-link:hover a > i {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  color: #0b0a08;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #9ecaed;
}
.m-link a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #e2e2e2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9114d9acc8.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="social-links">
    <ul>
      <li class="m-link">
        <a href=""><i class="far fa-envelope"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li class="m-link">
        <a href=""><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li class="m-link">
        <a href=""><i class="far fa-address-card"></i></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Didn't work man, like this the effect apply only on the link and not on the entire element, as you can see I'm try to create a circle button around the icon, I would like to be able to trigger the effect no matter where the cursor is (on the "li" element or on the icon)

Comment: ok well what is the effect taht you want? b/c right now it is triggered on hover over the .m-link class which is higher than your a tag so yes it is triggered by hover anywhere on the a tag right now. But I understand you want a different effect? Do you have an example somwhere maybe I can see ?